# Android: json paring

Tags: android, json

I am getting the folowing response from server side> I need to parse this and then store it in database.

```
  {"navigation_entries":{
   "home":{"forward_icon":"arrowright","link_name":"Home","highlighted_icon_with_text":"home_h","banner_image":"midbanner","children":         ["favorites","calendar","offers","wineries","settings"],"icon_without_text":"home_n","type":"home_page","highlighted_icon_without_text":"home_h","icon_with_text":"home_n"},
   "wineries":{"display_name":"Wineres","line_template":"wineries_list_template","forward_icon":"arrowright","link_name":"Wineries","highlighted_icon_with_text":"wineries_h","icon_without_text":"wineries","type":"leaf_list","leaf_template":"wineries_leaf_template","section":"wineries","icon_with_text":"wineries_n"},
   "more":{"display_name":"More","forward_icon":"arrowright","link_name":"More","highlighted_icon_with_text":"more_h","children":["favorites","calendar","offers","wineries","settings"],"icon_without_text":"more","type":"navigation_list","icon_with_text":"more_n"},
   "offers_all":{"display_name":"Offers : All","line_template":"offers_all_list_template","forward_icon":"arrowright","link_name":"All","children":["offers_all"],"type":"leaf_list","leaf_template":"offers_all_leaf_template","section":"offers_all"},
   "calendar":{"line_template":"calendar_list_template","forward_icon":"arrowright","highlighted_icon_with_text":"calendar_h","icon_without_text":"calendar","list_name":"Calendar","type":"calendar","leaf_template":"calendar_leaf_template","section":"events","icon_with_text":"calendar_n"},
   "offers":{"display_name":"Offers","forward_icon":"arrowright","link_name":"Offers","highlighted_icon_with_text":"offers_h","children":["offers_all"],"icon_without_text":"offers","type":"navigation_list","icon_with_text":"offers_n"}},"type":"navigation"}
```

I need to get the the names of entries like home, wineries, more, offers_all,calendar, offers or whatever the names come these namnes are changing  every time, And then get the values of forwardicon, link_name, highlighted_icon_with_text etc.

Can anyone help me over this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you browsed through some of the [json+android tagged questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json+android) already? There are tons of tips and answers concerning similar questions. As spoiler: you can for example use [`JSONObject`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) from the Android API for this, but numerous 3rd party libraries exist as well.

Comment: @MH. you are right, i thought i should catch him out but now in future i will never answer to the question of ekjyot

Comment: Because never describes question very well and raising doubts one by one, instead he should write question properly.

Comment: Try your hand: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+json+parsing

Comment: is your JSON string valid JSON? paste it here and check.http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: If you look at the 'related' column to your right, you'll see _many_ very similar questions. Perhaps one of those has the information you need? Unless you can edit this to be much more specific (and indicate that other questions here did not solve your problem), this is rather localized.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) and [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) classes to parse JSON response.

And use below methods:

1. [getJsonObject()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject%28java.lang.String%29)
2. [getJsonArray()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONArray%28java.lang.String%29)
3. [getString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29), [getInt()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getInt%28java.lang.String%29).....

Update:
Try it in your way, but let me give you starting point:

```
JSONObject objJson = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONObject objMain = objJson.getJsonObject("navigation_entries");

JSONObject objHome = objMain.getJsonObject("home");
JSONObject objWineries = objMain.getJsonObject("wineries");
// And same way for "more","offers_all","calendar", "offers"

 // How you get Values/Array from JsonObject
String strDisplayName = objWineries.getString("display_name");
String strForwardIcon = objWineries.getString("forward_icon");
```

Comment: I have already done that like the folowing:                   JSONArray navigation_values=navigation.names();

Comment: @ekjyot thats why you have posted code here, right? You should post the code here

Comment: @ekjyot I am sure you are using GSON library, have you tried as i have mentioned above?

Comment: @ekjyot Have you mentioned this in question? that you are not getting same response but difference.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4770/discussion-between-ekjyot-and-paresh-mayani)

Comment: @ekjyot You really should be more specific in your question. People can't keep continuously updating their answers based on more input from you. If they do, they'll edit their question right into a wiki status which isn't fair, and it's also quite mentally taxing.

Comment: @TimPost You are right about, even i have given answers to this user's many question and pulled my hair, i just realized

Answer (score 0):

The android JSONObject class should be able to parse all this for you automatically. Just do:

```
JSONObject myJSON = new JSONObject(your_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

check the below link once[Json parsing jar file](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html)

from this we are getting the jar file ,By using thta jar file we can easily parse the lot of data .